# How to access the ranch_owner object from watermelondb object

Tags: javascript, json, object, watermelondb

i have  this object I want to get address inside `ranch_owner` , i am using watermelondb there must a way or function i can access the relational data like this but not working , i read the documentation but didn't found anything helpful.

[image]